# CSS Background Image Transition When Scrolling

Tags: css, background-image

Does someone know of a tutorial/explanation for the effect like on - http://flandriatype.com/

How is the background image changing as I scroll?

PS: Site loads slowly initially, so be patient

Comment: Search for **parallax scrolling**

Answer (score 0):

It's a type of parallax, I've found [this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) plugin useful, but if you google 'parallax' tutorials you'll find a lot. Hope this helps :)